# Can HP m476dn MFP be configured to lookup email from AD/LDAP

Tags: ldap

I am considering to buy HP [m476dn](http://www.shopping.hp.com/en_US/home-office/-/products/Printers/HP-LaserJet/CF386A) MFP. Going through the specs it is no clear if the device can lookup for email address from the LDAP server.

What I would like is to be able to send scans via email to recipients by typing just a few letters and that the list of matching emails from our AD/LDAP is offered.

I downloaded user manual and such functionality is not mentioned under configuration. My two other MFP's from Xerox and Konica Minolta can perform this.

Do you know if HP m476 can perform such lookup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the HP M476 can do LDAP lookups.  See the instructions here: http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/learnUseDisplay/?javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.prp_efb5c0793523e51970c8fa22b053ce01=wsrp-navigationalState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c04085355-3%257CdocLocale%253Den_US&javax.portlet.tpst=efb5c0793523e51970c8fa22b053ce01&sp4ts.oid=5245583&ac.admitted=1403787990072.876444892.492883150

Wow, that's an ugly URL.

Comment: Thanks, I think this was the last doubt for me. If you own this MFP, are you happy with its performance? I need it for a section of approx. 30 people printing out around 1000 and scanning 2000 pages /month.

Comment: Product recommendations are [Off-Topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) for this site